# Access values from next line within for-loop to continue and break?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, continue

In the given data set I need to multiply values from different blocks with each other.

**I want to access data from next line within for loop and then build the list and create a product if the block value matches** but the examples I have looked so far isn't quite helping. Actually, this data is just a part of the big data and I need some explanation on any provided solution on how/why is it working.

`So,for X(set) I have to multiply: 0.25*0.1*0.83 (since they belong to same block`

```
block   X_set
2480    0.25
2480    0.1
2480    0.083
2651    0.43
2651    0.11
2651    0.23
```

My code is as follows:

```
test_q = open("test_question.txt", "r+")
header = test_q.readline()
data_q = test_q.read().rstrip("\n")

product=1.0
value_list = []

row = data_q.split("\n")

for line in row:
    block = line.split("\t")
    X_list = block[1].split()
    X_value = float(block[1])
    value_list = value_list + X_list
    product = product*X_value

print(value_list)
print(product)
```

The result is:

```
['0.25', '0.1', '0.083', '0.43', '0.11', '0.23']
2.2573925000000003e-05
```

But, in the print I want

```
['0.25', '0.1', '0.083']
0.0002075

['0.43', '0.11', '0.23']
0.010879
```

So, I want to access the index value from the next line so the for-loop can continue or break.

I have tried using to access the block value from next line:

```
    for i in range(0, len(row)-1):
    next_line = row[i+1]
```

How, can I improve this code?

**So, how to inject the break and continue function within this for-loop?**

- I don't want to use a fixed value for blocks since this is a long file and the block value will change.
- Also, the row with same block values may not be next to each other.
- Also, i don't need solution on pandas since this is just a part of big file which is exclusive mined using for-if-else loop.

Thanks much in advance !

Comment: What didn't work about your solution?

Comment: I am able to access the next set of lines and value using `for i in range` method. But, I am not able to develop further condition to apply `break` and `continue` to get the desired results. Can you provide some input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

res = defaultdict(list)
with open('file') as f:
    for r in f:
        k, v = r.split()
        res[k].append(v)

for v in res.values():
    print(v)
    print(reduce(mul, (float(f) for f in v), 1))
```

your problem is that you'd have to check every row to find a match, which would be a pain. it's easier just to store in a dict and then print out the results at the end. (if you care about order, you can use an `OrderedDict`)

edit for @everestial007's question in comments:

```
res = defaultdict(lambda: 1.0)
with open('file') as f:
    for r in f:
        k, v = r.split()
        res[k] *= float(v)
for k, v in res.items():
    res[k] = [str(v)]
```

Comment: In English - You can use the block column as a key for a dict. All entries with the same block code will be stored in the same list. Then, you can iterate through the list and, for each block code, print the list of values and their products.

Comment: it would be better in space sence  to keep in `res` product of iterated item not list of them.

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov i initially wrote it that way, but he says he wants to print both the component values and the final product, so i changed it

Comment: Thanks much  ! it is working after such a pain. I will have to see how I an fit this inside my big code. Thanks much again ~

Comment: Hi @acushner: in the situation if I want the result output to be: `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2480: ['0.002075'], 2651: ['0.010879']})`    
  what should I do. I have tried using data.items() but cannot use the `reduce(mul())` function.

Comment: why do you want to store these as single-element lists of strings when it is actually a single number? i'll edit the answer to show you how to do what you want.

Comment: to be clear, i would not do the last 2 lines at all (no reason to convert `.002` to `['.002']`), but this will answer your question